# Grails springSecurityService.getCurrentUser() is Null when using custom AuthenticationProvider

Tags: grails, spring-security

One controller in my app needs to be accessible by users authenticated against an external database.

I have set up a custom user object,

```
class CustomUserDetails extends GrailsUser {

    final String externalId

    CustomUserDetails(String username, String password, boolean enabled,
        boolean accountNonExpired, boolean credentialsNonExpired,
        boolean accountNonLocked,
        Collection<GrantedAuthority> authorities,
        long id, String externalId) {

        super(username, password, enabled, accountNonExpired,
        credentialsNonExpired, accountNonLocked, authorities, id)

        this.externalId = externalId 
    }       
}
```

and a custom AuthenticationProvider

```
class CustomAuthenticationProvider implements AuthenticationProvider {
    def springSecurityService

    Authentication authenticate(Authentication customAuth) {

    /* Do stuff to validate the user's credentials here */

        def userDetails = new CustomUserDetails(customAuth.getPrincipal(), customAuth.getCredentials(), true, true, true, true, 
                [new GrantedAuthorityImpl('ROLE_SPECIAL_USER')], 9999999, "externalDatabaseIdString")

        def token = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(userDetails, null, userDetails.authorities)

        return token
    }

    boolean supports(Class authentication) {
        return true
    }
}
```

I've made entries in Config.groovy to add this to the springsecurity.providerNames list, and added the following to conf/spring/resources.groovy

```
beans = {
customAuthenticationProvider(info.proadvisors.auth.CustomAuthenticationProvider){ bean ->   bean.autowire = "byName" }

userDetailsService(org.codehaus.groovy.grails.plugins.springsecurity.GormUserDetailsService){ bean -> bean.autowire = "byName" }
}
```

Here's the problem - in my controller, springSecurityService is being injected but springSecurityService.getCurrentUser() is null, and returns a null pointer exception when I try to access the externalId property that should be on the authenticated user object.

If, in my CustomAuthenticationProvider, instead of creating an instance of CustomUserDetails I use GormUserDetailsService to give me a GrailsUser object and use that to build the token, the controller works properly and getCurrentUser() works.

Any ideas on why this isn't working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

springSecurityService.getPrincipal() gives me what I'm looking for.

Not sure why getCurrentUser() doesn't work while getPrincpal() does, but it is what it is.